# MySQL Select Day Streak

Tags: mysql

This question is similar to the one answered here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/929846/1/0

```
Id    UserId  Timestamp
1     1       2012-12-01
2     2       2012-12-02
3     1       2012-12-02
4     2       2012-12-02
5     1       2012-12-03
6     3       2012-12-02
7     2       2012-12-03
8     3       2012-12-03
```

I'd like to retrieve the current streak for a user `1`. The expected result is `3` if today's date is `2012-12-03`.

The user will never have more than one entry in the same space of 24 hours.

If they have 4 records, their streak is 4. If they have 2 records, their streak is 2. If their last record is more than 24 hours ago, their streak is 0.

How can I calculate the streak using just a MySQL query?

**Rephrase**

A "streak" is defined as the number of *consecutive* days (`Timestamp`) having an entry for a given `UserId`.

Need help writing sql (or maybe a Stored Function) that, given a `UserId` and an ending `Timestamp`, returns the `streak`.

Comment: Can you include expected result for the sample data provided?

Comment: What's your primary key?

Comment: @Strawberry, I didn't include one as it wasn't relevant to the example data? I'll add it in though.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos, done!

Comment: If a user can only have one entry within 24 hours, then (user_id,timestamp) forms a natural key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT MAX(streak) AS streak
FROM (
  SELECT Id, UserId, `Timestamp`,
         DATEDIFF(NOW(), `Timestamp`),
         @streak := IF( DATEDIFF(NOW(), `Timestamp`) - @days_diff > 1, @streak, 
                       IF(@days_diff := DATEDIFF(NOW(), `Timestamp`), @streak+1, @streak+1))  AS streak                                        
  FROM mytable
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @streak := 0, @days_diff := -1) AS vars
  WHERE UserId = 1 AND `Timestamp` <= NOW()
  ORDER BY `Timestamp` DESC) AS t
```

The query uses `@streak` variable to incrementally update the streak number. The variable keeps being incremented as long as there is no gap bigger than one day between two consecutive records.

Note that `@days_diff` is initialized to `-1` so that if the *last* record, which is processed *first*, is more than 24 hours ago, the streak is set to `0`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd7876/1)

Comment: This is a life saver! Thanks a bunch. Small thing to bear in mind is that if there are no rows at all for a user then the returned result is `NULL`, as opposed to `0` but that's all good.

Comment: Thanks! This is so awesome. I forked your MySql demo here to make it easier to understand and allow people to change the NOW() to any arbitrary date (so that the demo dataset still produces the expected streak result): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b06617/5

Comment: This demo does not work now. The streak is 0 in your query result. I guess the `@days_diff:=  ...` in the IF statement is not executed properly..

Comment: Yes it does work. The only this missing is handling multiple values the same day (so if there are 2 values for a day, it should count as 1)

Comment: @Ryan, your fiddle is awesome! Is it possible to omit records from the same day? If a user one logs in twice a day, then both logins are calculated in the streak

Comment: @erdomester My MySQL skills aren't great, unfortunately. I'd love to hear if you get it figured out, though!

Comment: @Ryan as a matter of fact I did! http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b06617/38