# Consecutive 7 day streak query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table below as

```
events 

  user_id |     created_at  |   url
    int          datetime     varchar
```

I am trying to calculate the percentage of users as a float that had at least one 7-day streak of visiting the same URL

I am tryin the below query but does not give me right output, is there a reason this isnt working as I am confused

```
with x as (

     select count(user_id) as allusers
     from events
), y as 

( select count(e2.user_id) as users
     from events e
       join events e2
     on e.user_id = e2.user_id
     and e.url = e2.url
     and e2.created_at = DATE_ADD(e.created_at, INTERVAL 6 DAY)
)


select ROUND(users * 1.0 / allusers,2) as precent_of_users
from x,y
```

Comment: Provide a sample - CREATE TABLE script for the table, INSERT INTO with some sample data (2 users, 5-7 rows per user is enough) and desired output (for 3-day streak period, where only one user have such attendance).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Select Day Streak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35257121/mysql-select-day-streak)